# Getting This Error PHP Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Language\LanguageClient' not found

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to use the Google Cloud Language APIs.

Below are the steps that I followed -

Download PHP Files from the GitHub - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php

In my root folder, I have the exact same directory structure.

I ran composer require google/cloud and google/cloud-language

It created vendor folder in 'src' folder.

I created a testnlp.php file the same code as on this page for Google NLP - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php

I ran testnlp.com but I am getting below error -

"Getting This Error PHP Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Language\LanguageClient' not found "

Please help. What am I doing wrong ?

I am using shared hosting with PHP5.5 version.

Comment: composer require google/cloud-language